# Specifying the foreign key in a has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, has-many-through

I have the following three models: User, Project, and Assignment.

A User `has_many` Projects through an assignment. However, Assignment actually has *two* foreign keys that relate to a User: `user_id` (representing the user who was assigned the project) and `completer_id` (representing the user who completed the project).

Often, `user_id` and `completer_id` will be the same (if the user who was assigned the project completes it). However, if another user completes it, user_id and completer_id will be different.

In my User model, I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :assignments
  has_many   :incomplete_assignments, :class_name => 'Assignment',
    :conditions  => 'completer_id IS NULL'
  has_many   :completed_assignments, :class_name => 'Assignment',
    :foreign_key => 'completer_id'

  # this is the important one
  has_many   :incomplete_projects,
    :through     => :assignments,
    :source      => :project,
    :conditions  => 'completer_id IS NULL'
end
```

I would like to make another association, called `:completed_projects`, which uses `completer_id` as the foreign key for the User in the `:through` model, rather than `:user_id`. Is it possible to do this?

And, as an aside, I am aware of the `:foreign_key` option. However, this option is ignored when using `:through`, so I'd like to know if there's a way to do this without it.

Finally, I should mention that I'm open to other designs, if it can't be done this way and someone can think of a better way.

Comment: Welcome to trying to do something moderately complex with ActiveRecord. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use SQL for the selection if ActiveRecord can't easily express the relationship out of the box:

```
has_many :completed_projects,
:class_name => "Project",
:finder_sql => 'SELECT p.* FROM projects p ' +
  'INNER JOIN assignments a ON p.id=a.project_id ' +
  'INNER JOIN users u on u.id=a.completer_id ' +
  'WHERE u.id=#{id}'
```

Comment: From what I can tell, this is the only way to do it. Thanks a bunch for this.

Comment: unfortunately, using :finder_sql breaks chaining. `user.completed_projects.limit(2)` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have other meta data in your assignments table?

If not I would just use habtm and add the completer_id to the projects table instead, it makes sense to live there anyway.

If you need/want to use has_many :through you could look at using named_scopes (Rails version permitting) so you could say `user.projects.completed` and `user.projects.incomplete`